# Calculation table2 data and updated to table1 LAravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
Table1

id  name     calculated_rating  
1   xyz  2  
2   abc  4.5
3   zzz  1
4   ddd      3
5   eee      2

Table2

id  f_id    rating
1   1   3
2   2   4
3   2   5
4   3   1
5   1   2
6   4   3
7   5   2
```

I have two tables one is Table1 and other is Table2 
In table2 f_id that is foreign_key Table1 id is primary_key
Now Table2 has rating I want to added the calculate average rating in Table1 whenever Table2 increase rating it calculate average and update into Table1 calculated_rating field

How to achieve this in laravel

Comment: Use avg() function of mysql

Comment: please improve your question with query of Table2 store method; I dont know you use Query Builder or Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you add records to `table2` like following you need to update `current_rating` value in `table1`.

Example,

```
id = 7   
f_id = 5   
rating = 2
```

You can create model for each table such as `Table1` and `Table2` using `artisan` command.

Now, Insert records like this:

```
$table2 = new Table2();
$table2->f_id = 5;
$table2->rating = 2;
$table2->save();
```

Now update new rating like this:

```
Table1::where('id',$table2->f_id)->update(['calculated_rating'=> Table2::where('f_id',$table2->f_id)->avg('rating')]);
```

Hope, this might help you.